# SimpleDateFormat parse for DTG format

Tags: simpledateformat

I am really confused with the SimpleDateFormat object. Here is the code :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("DDHHmm MMM yy", Locale.ENGLISH);

String dateString = "312230 MAR 10";
try 
{
    Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println("Original string: " + dateString);
    System.out.println("Parsed date    : " + date.toString());
}
catch (ParseException e) 
{
    System.out.println("ERROR: could not parse date in string \"" +
                dateString + "\"");
}
```

and this is the output :

```
Original string: 312230 MAR 10
Parsed date    : Sun Jan 31 22:30:00 EST 2010
```

I really expected the output to be

```
Parsed date    : Wed Mar 31 22:30:00 EST 2010
```

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong? It would be deeply appreciated. I am using java 1.6_27.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the simpleDateFormat pattern by "ddHHmm MMM yy" return the expected output

```
Original string: 312230 MAR 10
Parsed date    : Wed Mar 31 22:30:00 CEST 2010
```

DD on uppercase means day of year. In your example day 31 is in January, how your output, and not in March

Comment: I knew it had to be something silly. Thank you very much for responding.

Answer (score 0):

In SimpleDateFormat :

**D** represent the Day in year.For example- 31 as value of DD will give you the 31st day from 1st Jan.So,31st day of a year starting with 1st Jan will be 31st Jan.

**d** represent the Day in month.For ex- if 31 is given as value of dd,and MMM is MAR,then it will be 31st May.

More in [SimpledateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).